# How to make two thread communicate through handler?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have form that button can auto re-size their size when mouse hover on button and default their size when mouse is exited. It work normally first time but after i try it more than one time their size is enlarged that i can not control normally.

```
ImageIcon ima=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\chen rina\\Pictures\\win.png");
ImageIcon icon;
Thread thr;
Runnable r=new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       int i=40;
        while(i!=80){
             try{
                 Thread.sleep(20);
     Image scale=ima.getImage().getScaledInstance(i,i,Image.SCALE_FAST);
                  icon=new ImageIcon(scale);
                  btn2.setIcon(icon);
                  i=i+5;
                }
             catch(Exception ex){}         
        }
    }
};

private void btn2MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    thr=new Thread(r);
    thr.start();
}                                 

Runnable res=new Runnable() {
      int i;
    @Override
    public void run() {
       int i=80;
        while(i!=40){
             try{
                  Thread.sleep(20);
 Image scale=ima.getImage().getScaledInstance(i,i,Image.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING);
                   icon=new ImageIcon(scale);
                    btn2.setIcon(icon);
                    i=i-5;
                }
               catch(Exception ex){}         
        }
    }
};

private void btn2MouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                 
         thr=new Thread(res);
         thr.start();
}
```

Comment: Why not use one thread, and have it wait until mouse exit.. the problem is now that you have no controll of the scale field...

Comment: i use two thread because first for narrow size and second for enlargment. is that right?

Answer (score 4):

Your code violates Swing thread integrity rules by making Swing calls, here `setIcon(...)` from within a background state. Having said that, why not simplify all of this by:

- Reading in and creating and storing your ImageIcons once and only once
- **Never** ignore exceptions as you're doing. That's unsafe coding.
- Most important, use a Swing Timer to simply swap icons every 20 msec, and have no fear about violating Swing threading rules.

Your grow Timer's ActionListener could be as simple as this:

```
// a private inner class
private class GrowListener implements ActionListener {
    private int index = 0;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // assuming the button is called button and the list iconList
        button.setIcon(iconList.get(index));
        index++;

        if (index >= iconList.size()) {
            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
        }
    }
}
```

---

The iconList would look something like:

```
private List<Icon> iconList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And you could fill it with code looking something like:

```
for (int i = startLength; i <= endLength; i += step) {
    Image img = originalImg.getScaledInstance(i, i, Image.SCALE_FAST);
    iconList.add(new ImageIcon(img));
}
```

And a more complete and runnable example:

[image: Resizeable Icon]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ResizeIconTest extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private static final int START_LENGTH = 40;
    private static final int END_LENGTH = 120;
    private static final int STEP = 5;
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 20;
    private static final String URL_SPEC = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/"
            + "thumb/2/2b/Oryx_gazella_-_Etosha_2014_square_crop.jpg/"
            + "600px-Oryx_gazella_-_Etosha_2014_square_crop.jpg";
    private JButton button = new JButton();
    private ResizeIcon resizeIcon;

    public ResizeIconTest() throws IOException {
        add(button);

        URL imageUrl = new URL(URL_SPEC);
        BufferedImage originalImg = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
        resizeIcon = new ResizeIcon(button, originalImg, START_LENGTH,
                END_LENGTH, STEP, TIMER_DELAY);
        button.setIcon(resizeIcon.getSmallestIcon());

        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                resizeIcon.grow();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                resizeIcon.shrink();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ResizeIconTest mainPanel = null;
        try {
            mainPanel = new ResizeIconTest();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ResizeIconTest");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

class ResizeIcon {
    private List<Icon> iconList = new ArrayList<>();
    private AbstractButton button;
    private int delayTime;
    private Timer growTimer;
    private Timer shrinkTimer;

    public ResizeIcon(AbstractButton button, BufferedImage originalImg,
            int startLength, int endLength, int step, int delayTime) {
        this.button = button;
        this.delayTime = delayTime;

        for (int i = startLength; i <= endLength; i += step) {
            Image img = originalImg.getScaledInstance(i, i, Image.SCALE_FAST);
            iconList.add(new ImageIcon(img));
        }
    }

    public Icon getSmallestIcon() {
        return iconList.get(0);
    }

    public void grow() {
        if (growTimer != null && growTimer.isRunning()) {
            return; // let's not run this multiple times
        }

        if (button.getIcon() == iconList.get(iconList.size() - 1)) {
            return; // don't run if already at largest size
        }

        growTimer = new Timer(delayTime, new GrowListener());
        growTimer.start();
    }

    public void shrink() {
        if (shrinkTimer != null && shrinkTimer.isRunning()) {
            return; // let's not run this multiple times
        }

        if (button.getIcon() == iconList.get(0)) {
            return; // don't run if already at smallest size
        }

        shrinkTimer = new Timer(delayTime, new ShrinkListener());
        shrinkTimer.start();
    }

    private class GrowListener implements ActionListener {
        private int index = 0;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            button.setIcon(iconList.get(index));
            index++;

            if (index >= iconList.size()) {
                ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
            }
        }
    }

    private class ShrinkListener implements ActionListener {
        private int index = iconList.size() - 1;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            button.setIcon(iconList.get(index));
            index--;

            if (index < 0) {
                ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i never use swing timer. Can give me example?

Comment: i don't understand you said"Reading in and creating and storing your ImageIcons once and only once". Can you explain me?

Comment: @narason: you bet! Please check out the [Swing Timer Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) which has great explanations and is loaded with examples.

Comment: @narason: Regarding reading in... create a `List<Icon>`, and on program start up, get the original image, and then in a for loop create your scaled images, create ImageIcons out of them, and stuff them into the List you've made. Then when you need to grow or shrink your images, simply swap ImageIcons held in the List.

Comment: @narason: see ActionListener for one of your possible Timers.

Comment: @narason: for example, see sample program